# Using Traits to cover implementation requirements of Interfaces

Tags: php, oop, traits, composition

Recently i came across multiple articles that are implying using Traits to cover implementation of Interfaces. 
Example:

```
interface ArticleInterface
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTitle();
}

trait ArticleTrait
{
   /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return "article_title";
    }
}

abstract class AbstractArticle implements ArticleInterface
{
    use ArticleTrait;
}
```

[Some](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/traits-with-interfaces) even think that Traits implementing Interfaces should be available in PHP core.

Therefore i am trying to get a proper response on a question if this design pattern should be followed ? 
If yes, should PHPDoc description be written in both interface and trait (meaning it will be duplicated) ?
Any other details that i should take notice of when using this design ?

Comment: Imo, Traits are good choice for this case: provide a some default implementation without "real" inheritance. Simple way to reduce the boilerplate code. This looks like [default methods of interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in Java. I don't see any drawbacks of this design.

Answer (score 3):

Traits provide for compiler-assisted copy-and-paste. They are a form of code re-use. While class inheritance gives you code re-use vertically (child classes share code defined in their parents), traits give you code re-use horizontally: interface-sharing classes can use code defined in the trait.

So, yes, if you have *multiple* siblings sharing the same interface *and* implementation, then you may use traits to reduce code duplication. But, no, if you have only *one* class implementing an interface - as in your example - then traits add undeserved complexity.

I'd like to add one important point: traits don't, themselves, store state. Any member variable in the trait will ultimately be stored in the object consuming the trait. If you have some state information that should be considered "private" to the trait (and therefore unavailable in the object), then don't use traits for re-use. Instead, use service delegates.

Comment: What about PHPDocs then? Should it be in both interface and trait ?

Comment: Yes, because the trait and the interface are currently independent. If traits ever implement interfaces, then single source documentation would make sense.